# How to style JS document.write output from a loop using CSS

Tags: javascript

I'm just learning JS and trying to understand loops, I've created a very simple loop, however I want to style the loop output using CSS, like put each item into a grid layout.

I've seen  tags inside document.write () parentheses however wherever I put the  tag I get a SyntaxError for an unexpected '<'

Would someone kindly (and simply haha) explain where I'm going wrong and where the  tags can go (feels like i've tried everywhere)

Thanks

Here is my JS code (don't have a CSS yet as not been able to tag the JS)

```js
let motorbikeList = [ 
      { name: "Ducati V4r", horsepower: 240,  },
      { name: "Ducati V4", horsepower: 214,  },
      { name: "Ducati V2", horsepower: 155,  },
      { name: "Yamaha R1", horsepower: 197,  },
      { name: "Yamaha R6", horsepower: 133, }
    ]

    for (let i = 0; i < motorbikeList.length; i++) {        
      if (motorbikeList[i].horsepower >= 220) {
      document.write(motorbikeList[i].name + "(HP:" + motorbikeList[i].horsepower + "  ) - Wow!       that's alot of horsepower !" + '<br>');
    } else if (motorbikeList[i].horsepower){
       document.write(motorbikeList[i].name + "(HP:" + motorbikeList[i].horsepower + ")  <br> ") 
     } 
}
```

Comment: Don't use `document.write`. Create a `<div>` where you insert the data into. Then you can style the `<div>` however you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be after something like this:

```js
let motorbikeList = [ 
  { name: "Ducati V4r", horsepower: 240,  },
  { name: "Ducati V4", horsepower: 214,  },
  { name: "Ducati V2", horsepower: 155,  },
  { name: "Yamaha R1", horsepower: 197,  },
  { name: "Yamaha R6", horsepower: 133, }
]

for (let i = 0; i < motorbikeList.length; i++) {        
  if (motorbikeList[i].horsepower >= 220) {
  document.write("<div style='background-color:red;'>" + motorbikeList[i].name + "(HP:" + motorbikeList[i].horsepower + "  ) - Wow!       that's alot of horsepower !" + '</div>');
} else if (motorbikeList[i].horsepower){
   document.write("<div style='background-color:green;'>" + motorbikeList[i].name + "(HP:" + motorbikeList[i].horsepower + ")</div>") 
 } 
}
```

But it is worth looking at alternatives to `document.write` as a whole like Ostone0 has mentioned in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75237812/how-to-style-js-document-write-output-from-a-loop-using-css#comment132765522_75237812).

Answer (score 1):

Let's be clear, `document.write` is one of the worst things in javascript, you can instead say:

```
document.body.innerHTML = "whatever you want"
```

and if you need to add some text to the exists text you can use the `+=` operator instead of the `=` operator like that:

```
document.body.innerHTML += "another text"
```

And here you can use any HTML tag inside this code:

```
document.body.innerHTML = "<span> Welcome " + username + " </span><br/>"
```

or any other code.

---

*a small note*

if you need to concatenate strings with variable outputs, use the `template string` operator like this:

```
document.body.innerHTML = `<span> Welcome ${username} </span></br>`
```